# merge rows in php depened on mysql prev row

Tags: php, html, mysql

i've this database table

```
fromDay - toDay - fromHour-toHour 
1            1     08:00     14:00
1            1     15:00     18:00 
2            2     08:00     18:00
```

and i want in my html table with the help of php to check if the prev row has 
the same days then merge this rows into one tr in html table . any ideas how to do it ?

Comment: Previous row doesn't mean anything in SQL if you don't specify an order.

Comment: What data do you expect in the merged row ? Something like fromHour: 08:00 ; toHour: 18:00 ? What happens to the gap between 14:00 and 15:00 ?

Comment: i'm writing the query : SELECT fromDay,toDay,fromHour,toHour,rowId FROM `BussinessWorkHours`  order by fromDay,toDay" but what is my next step to check the prev row ?

Comment: @X.L.Ant the result should be : days 1-1 hours - 08:00 14:00 , 15:00 18:00 in one row on my html table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to check rows one by one. Just use this query as the datasource of your table :

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS('-', fromDay, toDay) as day,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(' ', fromHour , toHour) ORDER BY 1) as hours
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY fromDay,
         toDay
ORDER BY 1
```

- See [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3e566/9)

Answer (score 0):

How about saving the variable you want to compare outside of the while scope, and only echo'ing `</tr>` when the variables don't match? In pseudocode that would look something like:

```
$storedVar = "";

while(loop through database){
  if($storedVar == $databaseRow){
    echo TDs;
  } else{
    echo end TR, start TR
  }

  $storedVar = $databaseRow;
}
```